How to increase the number of log files: /var/log/mail.log* on macOS?
On my actual macOS, there are every day 7 flat files in /var/log of name mail.log* rotating at 23:00:
### 18:20       milky-way:/etc/asl      # ls -al /var/log/mail.log*
-rw-r-----@ 1 root  admin  333712 Dec  3 18:17 /var/log/mail.log
-rw-r-----  1 root  admin   44272 Dec  2 23:00 /var/log/mail.log.0.gz
-rw-r-----  1 root  admin   40376 Dec  1 23:00 /var/log/mail.log.1.gz
-rw-r-----  1 root  admin   37274 Nov 30 23:00 /var/log/mail.log.2.gz
-rw-r-----  1 root  admin   46093 Nov 29 23:00 /var/log/mail.log.3.gz
-rw-r-----  1 root  admin   52495 Nov 28 23:00 /var/log/mail.log.4.gz
-rw-r-----  1 root  admin   53763 Nov 27 23:00 /var/log/mail.log.5.gz
-rw-r--r--  1 root  admin   54454 Nov 26 23:00 /var/log/mail.log.6.gz
### 18:20       milky-way:/etc/asl      #

I would like to get a set of one full month of these flat syslog files i.e. 30.
I know these files are generated from the ASL database, and I tried to modify the file to push the store_ttl and ttl to 30.
### 18:24       milky-way:/etc/asl      # cat /etc/asl/com.apple.mail
# mail facility has its own log file
? [= Facility mail] claim only
> /var/log/mail.log mode=0640 format=bsd rotate=seq compress store_ttl=30 ttl=30 file_max=5M all_max=50M
* file /var/log/mail.log
### 18:24       milky-way:/etc/asl      #

And next killed syslogd wigh HUP to make it reload the ASL modules configuration.
But I continue to have just 7 /var/log/mail.log*.
Which process is making the rotation of these /var/log/mail.log*?
How to configure this process?
so as to get a full month ( 30 ) of them ?

Read man logrotate logrotate.conf. logrotate is run via cron, /etc/logrotate.conf is where you can configure your "30 days" (why not 31 or 32 dsys?)

Read man newsyslog newsyslog.conf

@waltinator: there is no logrotate on macOS, and nearly nothing is fired through cron.

@tink: I already looked at /etc/newsyslog.conf which exists on macOS but it is not the one which manage the /var/log/mail.log rotation.

This is a bug in the way the tool aslmanager deals with the parameter ttl.
I was able to highlight this problem with the command:
/usr/bin/sudo aslmanager -dd 4 -module com.apple.mail

which output:
[...]
aslmanager starting dryrun
----------------------------------------
Processing module com.apple.mail
Checking file /var/log/mail.log
- Rename, move to destination directory, and compress as required
    no src files
- Check for expired files - TTL = 30 days                   ### correct
    dst files
      mail.log.0.gz
      mail.log.1.gz
      mail.log.2.gz
      mail.log.3.gz
      mail.log.4.gz
      mail.log.5.gz
      mail.log.6.gz
      mail.log.7.gz
      mail.log.8.gz
      mail.log.9.gz
  remove /var/log/mail.log.7.gz                             ### WRONG
  remove /var/log/mail.log.8.gz                             ### WRONG
  remove /var/log/mail.log.9.gz                             ### WRONG
  [...]

which shows that aslmanager is ignoring the explicit value and stick
to the default one which is 7.
The way to work around this internal bug was to change the way
aslmanager is fired automatically by launchd:
cd /System/Library/LaunchDaemons

stopped the scheduling of aslmanager:
/usr/bin/sudo launchctl unload com.apple.aslmanager.plist

modified the argument to start it to add: -ttl 0:
/usr/bin/sudo vi com.apple.aslmanager.plist

    [...]
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
            <string>aslmanager</string>
            <string>-ttl</string>
            <string>0</string>
    </array>
    [...]

restarted the scheduling of aslmanager:
/usr/bin/sudo launchctl unload com.apple.aslmanager.plist

